# How does the the linux kernel detect a usb device

Tags: kernel, usb

I am facing an issue with an embedded Linux platform. There is a USB hub device which connects to the main CPU. However, this USB device intermittently is not detected on some power cycles. I am trying to debug this.

How does the Linux kernel get notified of the presence of a USB device, and what is the low-level hardware event that a USB slave device sends to signal its presence to the host?

Any advice/clarification for the above queries would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It just pulls D+ and D- with high and lows which generates hardware interrupt. check `usb.c and `hub.c` underneath drivers/sub/core. This should get you started.

Comment: Thank you, Sagar.